# How to subtract date, then sum the results of the previous operation

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table Plane, the table Flight, which is basically a Flight that a Plane did, then for each flight I have solved M:N table which just holds foreign keys for Flight and Destination, 2 entries in table Destination, to know the difference between Departure and Arrival, table Destination has a connection to table Type( Departure and Arrival, which is set in another table, of 2 rows, "Zacetna" = Departure, "Koncna" = Arrival ). Table Destination also has a connection to table Date which contains Datetime.

I want to Subtract Arrival and Departure time for each Flight, then Sum the times if Plane has multiple Flights.

I have tried to just Subtract them all and then sub but that didn't work, then I have tried to Group By, but with no luck.

In the attached picture.
Plane called "Falcon FX 3000" has 2 flights, idFlight 5 and 6. To get the expected result I would have to do

`( Destination_6_Date - Destination_5_Date) + (Destination_4_Date - Destination_7_Date)`
but none of my solutions worked

```
SELECT d.Ime, letD.Destinacija_idDestinacija, l.idLet,tip.Tip,  t.Termin
FROM Letalo p
INNER JOIN Let l ON l.Letalo_idLetalo = p.idLetalo
INNER JOIN Let_Has_Destinacija letD on letD.Let_idLet = l.idLet
INNER JOIN Destinacija d on d.idDestinacija = letD.Destinacija_idDestinacija
INNER JOIN Termin t on t.idTermin = d.Termin_idTermin
INNER JOIN Tip_Destinacije tip on tip.idTip_Destinacije = Tip_Destinacije_idTip_Destinacije WHERE p.Naziv='Falcon FX 3000';
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97TFZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/utbCJ.png

```
Sorry for the ERDiagram for being in the different language
Letalo = Plane
Let = Flight
Let_Has_Destinacija = Solved M:N, holding Flight ID and Destination ID
Destinacija = Destination
Termin = Date
Tip_Destinacija = Type
```

**EDIT**
This is the successful GROUP BY query that returns valid calculations, now I just need to sum them. I am guessing this will be done with subquery, but I don't really understand that, as I am new to MySQL

```
SELECT d.Ime as Name, letD.Destinacija_idDestinacija as Destination, l.idLet as idFlight,tip.Tip as Type,  CAST(t.Termin as DATE), timediff(Max(t.Termin), min(t.Termin))
FROM Letalo p
INNER JOIN Let l ON l.Letalo_idLetalo = p.idLetalo
INNER JOIN Let_Has_Destinacija letD on letD.Let_idLet = l.idLet
INNER JOIN Destinacija d on d.idDestinacija = letD.Destinacija_idDestinacija
INNER JOIN Termin t on t.idTermin = d.Termin_idTermin
INNER JOIN Tip_Destinacije tip on tip.idTip_Destinacije = Tip_Destinacije_idTip_Destinacije WHERE p.Naziv='Falcon FX 3000'
GROUP BY l.idLet;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx91b.png

**EDIT 2**
By using temp tables, I managed to SUM the flights times, but I have to use 2 queries for this, which is not what I want.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTime;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTime (
SELECT timediff(Max(t.Termin), min(t.Termin)) as FlightTime
    FROM Letalo p
    INNER JOIN Let l ON l.Letalo_idLetalo = p.idLetalo
    INNER JOIN Let_Has_Destinacija letD on letD.Let_idLet = l.idLet
    INNER JOIN Destinacija d on d.idDestinacija = letD.Destinacija_idDestinacija
    INNER JOIN Termin t on t.idTermin = d.Termin_idTermin
    INNER JOIN Tip_Destinacije tip on tip.idTip_Destinacije = Tip_Destinacije_idTip_Destinacije WHERE p.Naziv='Falcon FX 3000'
GROUP BY l.idLet);

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(FlightTime))) as FlownTime FROM tempTime;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTime;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xDXP.png

**ACCEPTED ANSWER**

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    `Destination`, 
    `Type`,
    `Date`, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`Time_diff`))) as `Tot_Diff`
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.`Ime` as `Name`, 
        letD.`Destinacija_idDestinacija` as `Destination`, 
        l.`idLet` as idFlight,tip.`Tip` as `Type`,
        CAST(t.`Termin` as DATE) as `Date`, 
        timediff(Max(t.`Termin`), min(t.`Termin`)) as `Time_diff`
    FROM Letalo p
    INNER JOIN `Let` l 
        ON l.`Letalo_idLetalo` = p.`idLetalo`
    INNER JOIN `Let_Has_Destinacija` letD 
        on letD.`Let_idLet` = l.`idLet`
    INNER JOIN `Destinacija` d 
        on d.`idDestinacija` = letD.`Destinacija_idDestinacija`
    INNER JOIN `Termin` t 
        on t.`idTermin` = d.`Termin_idTermin`
    INNER JOIN `Tip_Destinacije` tip 
        on tip.`idTip_Destinacije` = `Tip_Destinacije_idTip_Destinacije` 
    WHERE p.Naziv = 'Falcon FX 3000'
    GROUP BY l.idLet
    ) as `main`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for providing a translation on the table names, and column names. What did your try for the group by? Edit your question and show what you tried.

Comment: Much better to show your sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Hello, thank you for welcome, I as for the sample data, it is in the 1st imgur picture linked, but I have made some progress on my own after sleeping over it.

@SloanThrasher I have provided an edit with the GROUP BY, that calculates the difference between the times, now I just need to sum times together

Comment: Just an FYI: When creating a question, post text instead of images. Sometimes when working on an answer, we copy and paste data and code from the question into a SQL fiddle in order to test/experiment with an answer. We can't copy/paste from an image, and few will bother to re-type what's in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should produce the result you describe. Basically, it takes the query you have, uses it as a sub-query
then sums the time differences.

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    `Destination`, 
    `Type`,
    `Date`, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`Time_diff`))) as `Tot_Diff`
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.`Ime` as `Name`, 
        letD.`Destinacija_idDestinacija` as `Destination`, 
        l.`idLet` as idFlight,tip.`Tip` as `Type`,
        CAST(t.`Termin` as DATE) as `Date`, 
        timediff(Max(t.`Termin`), min(t.`Termin`)) as `Time_diff`
    FROM Letalo p
    INNER JOIN `Let` l 
        ON l.`Letalo_idLetalo` = p.`idLetalo`
    INNER JOIN `Let_Has_Destinacija` letD 
        on letD.`Let_idLet` = l.`idLet`
    INNER JOIN `Destinacija` d 
        on d.`idDestinacija` = letD.`Destinacija_idDestinacija`
    INNER JOIN `Termin` t 
        on t.`idTermin` = d.`Termin_idTermin`
    INNER JOIN `Tip_Destinacije` tip 
        on tip.`idTip_Destinacije` = `Tip_Destinacije_idTip_Destinacije` 
    WHERE p.Naziv = 'Falcon FX 3000'
    GROUP BY l.idLet
    ) as `main`
GROUP BY `Name`,`Destination`,`Type`,`Date`;
```

Comment: Hello, I gave you an up vote.
Your code is correct. As I did more of the sql queries, I figured out how to do sub query. There is one small issue if anyone is checking out in the future.
You cant sum date directly, you have to cast it to the seconds, Sum, and then transform it back.
`SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`Time_diff`))) as `Tot_Diff`

Comment: Thanks and kudos on that catch. I updated the answer with your code.